# removing string in CSV file based on regex using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a csv file with rows like mentioned below.

```
{name:Test1,type:X1},{name:Test2,type:X2},{name:Default,type:X1},{name:Test3,type:X1},{name:Test4,type:X2}
```

I need to remove only parts of type X1. After removal the row should look like this

```
,{name:Test2,type:X2},,,{name:Test4,type:X2}
```

I tried sed command with regex like this..

```
sed -i 's/^{name:(?=[A-Z0-9]*).*,type:X1}$//g' abc.csv
```

After execution nothing is getting replaced or no errors.

I am new to Unix environment. Kindly let me know, what is the mistake i am doing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp:

```
sed -i 's/{name:[a-zA-Z0-9]*,type:X1}//g' abc.csv
```

1. The `^` and `$` tell the regex engine that the match string must extend from the start of the line to the end of the line. Since you want to match multiple strings within the line, you should leave those out.
2. The `foo(?=bar)` syntax is for [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It matches `foobar` but only `foo` is included in the match. You don't need this lookahead feature, and it was causing you to add a `.*` to match the name value, so removing this is a good idea in this case.
3. Your name value consists of both uppercase and lowercase letters, so you need to add `a-z` to your match class for the name value. If you want `sed` to operate [case-insensitively](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-10a), you should use the `I` modifier flag if you are using GNU sed; i.e., your match string would end in `//gI`.